# object reference not set to an instance of an object in linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a few classes, I need use them together.

a sample

```
public class members
{
    [Key]
    public Guid id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

public class comments
{
    [Key]
    public Guid id {get;set;}
    public members composer {get;set;}
    public string comment {get;set;}
}
```

I try this way

```
List<comments> listComments = new List<comments>();
using(db dc = new db())
{
    listComments = dc.comment.Where(x => x.id.Equals("an id")).ToList();
}
```

when I try get member name from comments it says object reference not set instance of object.

```
foreach(comments c in listComments)
{
    c.id //no problem
    c.comment //no problem
    c.composer.name //error?
}
```

**SOLUTION**
I was found solution with get members as list.

```
List<comments> listComments = new List<comments>();
List<members> lm = new List<members>();
using(db dc = new db())
{
    listComments = dc.comment.Where(x => x.id.Equals("an id")).ToList();
    lm = dc.member.ToList();
}




foreach(comments c in listComments)
{
    c.id //no problem
    c.comment //no problem
    lm.Where(u => u.id.Equals(c.member.id)).FirstOrDefault().name //that works good
}
```

Comment: it means the composer in the database has name column with Null value. check your database for Composer name, you ll see it.

Comment: Those class names should be UpperCamelCase and not plural.

Comment: @DarthVader I checked and no problem with member. Member exist with same Guid in comments table.

Comment: @SLaks not necessarily. he can have his own convention

Comment: @DarthVader Definitely not. If the column has a null value, the property will simply be null - an exception will not be thrown.

Comment: well it s a null pointer. what else can it be?

Comment: @DarthVader There are no pointers in .NET, and a null value type (which you describe) is not the same as a null reference.

Comment: :) yeah well i meant null reference actually:)

Answer (score 2):

LINQ-to-SQL gives lazy-loading by default. You need to force the child objects to load using the DataLoadOptions class.

```
List<comments> listComments = new List<comments>();
using(db dc = new db())
{
    var loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
    loadOptions.LoadWith<comments>(c => c.members);
    db.LoadOptions = loadOptions;

    listComments = dc.comment.Where(x => x.id.Equals("an id")).ToList();
}
```

You can also force the child objects to load by touching them within the database context

```
List<comments> listComments = new List<comments>();
using(db dc = new db())
{
    listComments = dc.comment.Where(x => x.id.Equals("an id")).ToList();

    var members = listComments.SelectMany(l => l.members);
}
```